# R: Solving for a variable (using the uniroot function)

Tags: r, equation-solving, nonlinear-equation, uniroot

I am rather new to R and really could need the help of the community with the following problem. I am trying to solve for the variable r in the following equation: **(EPS2 + r*DPS1-EPS1)/r^2)-PRC**. Here is my (unsuccessful) attempt on solving the problem (using the uniroot function):

```
EPS2 = df_final$EPS2

DPS1 = df_final$DPS1

EPS1 = df_final$EPS1

PRC = df_final$PRC

f1 = function(r) {
    ((df_final_test$EPS2 + r * df_final_test$DPS1-df_final_test$EPS1)/r^2)-df_final_test$PRC 
}

uniroot(f1,interval = c(1e-8,100000),EPS2, DPS1, EPS1, PRC , extendInt="downX")$root
```

> I then get the following error: *Error in f(lower, ...) :    unused
> arguments (c("      1.39", "      1.39", ...*

I am grateful for any tips and hints you guys could give me in regard to this problem. Or whether a different function/package would be better in this case.

Added a reprex (?) in case that helps anybody in helping me with this issue:

```
df <- structure(list(EPS1 = c(6.53, 1.32, 1.39, 1.71, 2.13), DPS1 = c(2.53, 0.63,
0.81, 1.08, 1.33, 19.8), EPS2 = c(7.57,1.39,1.43,1.85,2.49), PRC = c(19.01,38.27,44.82,35.27,47.12)), .Names = c("EPS1", "DPS1", "EPS2", "PRC"), row.names = c(NA,
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hi Jessica, can you provide a reprex? (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html)

Comment: @MarceloAvila Added it to the post. Hope this helps anybody who can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I have no experience with `uniroot()` and have not idea if the following makes sense, but it runs! The idea was to basically call `uniroot` for each row of the data frame.

Note that I modified the function `f1` slightly so each of the additional parameters has are to be passed as arguments of the function and do not rely on finding the objects with the same name in the parent environment. I also use `with` to avoid calling `df$...` for every variable.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.0
library(furrr)
#> Loading required package: future


df <- structure(list(EPS1 = c(6.53, 1.32, 1.39, 1.71, 2.13),
                     DPS1 = c(2.53, 0.63, 0.81, 1.08, 1.33, 19.8),
                     EPS2 = c(7.57,1.39,1.43,1.85,2.49),
                     PRC = c(19.01,38.27,44.82,35.27,47.12)),
                .Names = c("EPS1", "DPS1", "EPS2", "PRC"),
                row.names = c(NA,-5L), class = "data.frame")
df
#> Warning in format.data.frame(if (omit) x[seq_len(n0), , drop = FALSE] else x, :
#> corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
#>   EPS1  DPS1 EPS2   PRC
#> 1 6.53  2.53 7.57 19.01
#> 2 1.32  0.63 1.39 38.27
#> 3 1.39  0.81 1.43 44.82
#> 4 1.71  1.08 1.85 35.27
#> 5 2.13  1.33 2.49 47.12

f1 = function(r, EPS2, DPS1, EPS1, PRC) {
  (( EPS2 + r *  DPS1 - EPS1)/r^2) - PRC 
}

# try for first row 
with(df, 
     uniroot(f1, 
             EPS2=EPS2[1], DPS1=DPS1[1], EPS1=EPS1[1], PRC=PRC[1],
             interval = c(1e-8,100000), 
             extendInt="downX")$root)
#> [1] 0.3097291
# it runs! 


# loop over each row
vec_sols <- rep(NA, nrow(df))
for (i in seq_along(1:nrow(df))) {
  
  sol <- with(df, uniroot(f1, 
                          EPS2=EPS2[i], DPS1=DPS1[i], EPS1=EPS1[i], PRC=PRC[i],
                          interval = c(1e-8,100000), 
                          extendInt="downX")$root)
  vec_sols[i] <- sol
}
vec_sols
#> [1] 0.30972906 0.05177443 0.04022946 0.08015686 0.10265226


# Alternatively, you can use furrr's future_map_dbl to use multiple cores.
# the following will basically do the same as the above loop. 
# here with 4 cores. 
plan(multisession, workers = 4)
vec_sols <- 1:nrow(df) %>% furrr::future_map_dbl(
  .f = ~with(df, 
             uniroot(f1, 
                     EPS2=EPS2[.x], DPS1=DPS1[.x], EPS1=EPS1[.x], PRC=PRC[.x],
                     interval = c(1e-8,100000), 
                     extendInt="downX")$root
  ))
vec_sols
#> [1] 0.30972906 0.05177443 0.04022946 0.08015686 0.10265226


# then apply the solutions back to the dataframe (each row to each solution)
df %>% mutate(
  root = vec_sols
)
#> Warning in format.data.frame(if (omit) x[seq_len(n0), , drop = FALSE] else x, :
#> corrupt data frame: columns will be truncated or padded with NAs
#>   EPS1  DPS1 EPS2   PRC       root
#> 1 6.53  2.53 7.57 19.01 0.30972906
#> 2 1.32  0.63 1.39 38.27 0.05177443
#> 3 1.39  0.81 1.43 44.82 0.04022946
#> 4 1.71  1.08 1.85 35.27 0.08015686
#> 5 2.13  1.33 2.49 47.12 0.10265226
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can use `uniroot` if all coefficients are vectors rather than scalars. In this case, a straightforward approach is solving them in a math way, i.e.,

```
r1 <- (DPS1 + sqrt(DPS1^2-4*PRC*(EPS1-EPS2)))/(2*PRC)
```

and

```
r2 <- (DPS1 - sqrt(DPS1^2-4*PRC*(EPS1-EPS2)))/(2*PRC)
```

where `r1` and `r2` are two roots.

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a try! I was wondering if there is also an another way of doing it using a different package/function instead of using a "math way". I also need to use the same approach for more complex equations, where solving them in a "math way" might not be a feasible approach. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Jessica168 Since you are attempting to solve a vector `r` using `uniroot`, you should vectorize your function. Perhaps you should try `uniroot` element-wisely, such that each time a tuple of arguments is passed to `uniroot`. For example, we take the k-th values from `DPS1`, `PRC`, `EPS1` and `EPS2` and pass them to `uniroot` to obtain the k-th value of `r`.

Comment: Thanks for your input @ThomasIsCoding! I will try the element-wise approach if there is no other option available (I have 127834 observations so I would have to do it for each of them separately, which would take forever). But thank you very much!

Comment: @Jessica168 I would recommend the math way if you can solve it manually, which would be faster and more precise.